# Make Line Art lines thinner than the minimum

Tags: modifiers, grease-pencil, lineart

I have a very physically small scene where I am using the Line Art modifier to outline certain objects. I turned the Line Thickness down to 1, but because of the size of the objects 1 is still pretty thick. I can't adjust the size of the scene for a few reasons, so I'm wondering if there is a way to make the Line Art even thinner than the minimum thickness value.

I tried using the Thickness Modifier, but it seems like that also only goes down to this "1" thickness.

Comment: How did you do your line art? There are multiple ways to control thickness. You can set it from the render settings, from a gp object, ... Please [edit] your question to add detail. You can also post screenshots and [share your file](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3051/53447)